# Php csv upload error

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a csv file and save it in db. The problem is its returning Notice Error

> **Notice**: Use of undefined constant csv - assumed 'csv' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 5
>
> **Notice**: Use of undefined constant size - assumed 'size' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 5
>
> **Notice**: Undefined index: csv in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 5

I have stuck with it since 2 hours debugging, can some one please help fix.

Below is the code.

```
<?php    
include "../config/config.php";

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO case_view (
                    courtname, casenumber, year, pfname, plname, 
                    cell, fhearing, cstatus, cdescri
                ) VALUES  (
                    '" . addslashes($data[0]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[1]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[2]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[3]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[4]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[5]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[6]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[7]) . "',
                    '" . addslashes($data[8]) . "'
                )
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;
   // echo "Import Successfull";
}
```

?>

Comment: You may consider using `PDO` with `prepared statements` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `$_FILES[csv]` without `quotes` it will assume that `csv` is a constant, so wrap it up with `quotes` and try again. Try with -

```
if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 
    .....
    $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
```

Add a check for it -

```
if (!empty($_FILES['csv']['size']) && $_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) { 
       ..............
```

Comment: Thanks, by adding the Quotes 2 Notice error disappeared but still i get 1 notice error Notice: Undefined index: csv in D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 5

Comment: Now i do not see any error but its directly exiting the if loop

Comment: Add the form structure.

Comment: Ok, i had missed enctype=multipart/form-data now it works great and also save in db, but i get this notice error even though the data is inserted Notice: Undefined variable: data in D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. You open an `if` block on line 5, but never close it after your `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, i closed the if loop, but i started getting notice error
Notice: Use of undefined constant csv - assumed 'csv' in D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 5

Notice: Use of undefined constant size - assumed 'size' in D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: csv in D:\xampp\htdocs\nag\admin\process\upload_case.php on line 5